# How to simplify multiple same looking enumerations?

Tags: java, interface, enums

I got multiple enumerations, which all implement the same interface AnimationSet, but with some more fields, such as filename and each enum had to implement the exact same getFilename().

```
interface AnimationSet{
    String getPath();
    String getFilename();
}

public enum HammerAnimationSet implements AnimationSet{
    ONE("1"),
    TWO("2"),
    THREE("3"),
    FOUR("4");

    private static String path = "hammer/";
    private String filename;

    private HammerAnimationSet(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }

}

public enum ShopAnimationSet implements AnimationSet{
    HEART("heart"),
    MANA("mana bottle"),
    LUCK("clover");

    private static String path = "shop/";
    private String filename;

    private ShopAnimationSet(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }

}
```

Edit: I now use these enums to fill a `List<List<List<Image>>>` where the first list corresponds the enum and a group of animations, the second list consists of all the animations in the group, and the third list (with images) represent all the images in one specific animation.
Later I can get an image from the outside from this list.

Now I was looking for a way to simplify/shorten this code (The methods and fields are all the same).

I thought about a superclass, but that was not possible because an enum already extends Enum. I also thought about changing the enumerations to classes, but I would like to keep the enum values. I also thought about an abstract interface, but what I thought about wasn't possible.

Could you help thinking for a way to achieve simpification.

Comment: This might be more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although not voting to close.

Comment: what you want to simplify here? you have here only constructor and getters

Comment: If you ask this on Code Review, you would need to include a lot more context to be on-topic enough - how are you using these classes in your code?

Comment: @user902383 Each enum has the exact same constructor and getters, I would like to get rid of the duplication (it really was copy and paste).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using delegation instead of inheritance:

```
public class AnimationSet {
    private final String path, filename;

    public AnimationSet(String path, String filename) {
        this.path = path;
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }
}

public enum HammerAnimationSet {
    ONE("1"),
    TWO("2"),
    THREE("3"),
    FOUR("4");

    final AnimationSet animationSet;

    HammerAnimationSet(String filename) {
        animationSet=new AnimationSet("hammer/", filename);
    }
    public AnimationSet getAnimationSet() {
        return animationSet;
    }
}

public enum ShopAnimationSet {
    HEART("heart"),
    MANA("mana bottle"),
    LUCK("clover");

    final AnimationSet animationSet;

    private ShopAnimationSet(String filename){
        animationSet=new AnimationSet("shop/", filename);
    }
    public AnimationSet getAnimationSet() {
        return animationSet;
    }
}
```

So the features of `AnimationSet` can be expanded without the need to adapt any of the `enum`s.